# How to make a self updating variable in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models, Employee and Designation. I want to count and update no. of Employees in a particular Designation. The project is a multiple user project, So I need a queryset, that focuses regarding the particular user.

**Models.py**

```
class Designation(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="designation",null=True,blank=True)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     count = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="employee",null=True,blank=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     contact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
     dateJoined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=False,null=True)
     designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
```

**I need the Variable count in Designation model to auto-update and count the no. of Employees holding a particular Designation**

Comment: Try this [thing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading) from Docs

Comment: This can be done using Model Managers, see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) might help you.